# How to get image preview in frontend form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, frontend, magento2.4.2, ui-form

I have created a module that creates a form at frontend, but I'm unable to get the image upload preview out there.

Can we put preview.html in frontend/templates? If not, then how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to do that, after upload image it will show on frontend,

```
var fimagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
                var fileInput = document.getElementById('featured_img');
                var size = parseFloat(fileInput.files[0].size / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);
                
                var filePath = fileInput.value;
            
                // Allowing file type
                var allowedExtensions = 
                        /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;
                
                if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
                    alert('Invalid file, Please upload only jpg/jpeg and png files are allowed with Max limit 5MB');
                    fileInput.value = '';
                    return false;
                } else {

                    if (input.files) {
                        if(size <= 5){
                            var filesAmount = input.files.length;
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function(event) {
                                jQuery('div.gallery-img').html('<img src="'+event.target.result+'"><span class="remove"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');
                            }
                            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                }
            };
```